# How to place haskell field names in different name spaces?

Tags: haskell

Consider the following two types:

```
data Point=Point{x::Float,y::Float}
data Rectangle = {upperLeft::Point, bottomRight::Point}
data Square = {upperLeft::Point, bottomRight::Point}
```

the ghc compiler complains that the upperLeft field name in Rectangle conflicts with that of Square. This seems strange as on the face of it each field name should be in the namespace of the type, otherwise one cannot reuse field names, and I suspect that would be a common enough expectation.

For example to define a variable we write:

```
let a=Rectangle{upperLeft=Point 2 3, bottomRight=Point 7 7}
let a=Square{upperLeft=Point 2 3, bottomRight=Point 7 7}
```

From this we can see that we ought to be able to expect that each field name should be within their respective type namespace.

Is my usage correct or are my expectations wrong? Is there someway to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Since objects can be accessed through their field names, the compiler must be able to infer an object's type from its field name.  For instance, in

```
boundingBox x = bottomRight x - upperLeft x
```

the accessors `bottomRight` and `upperLeft` are used to infer the type of `x`.  If multiple types were allowed to have the same accessor name, then it wouldn't be possible to infer the type.

To avoid name collisions, a common convention is to put a prefix on all field names.  This convention is used in the GHC project.

```
data Rectangle = {rc_upperLeft :: Point, rc_bottomRight :: Point}
data Square =    {sq_upperLeft :: Point, sq_bottomRight :: Point}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell, creating a record type also creates accessor functions. 
For example, you could run: `x (upperLeft a)` on either of the variables you defined above to get 2.
Here's a [summary of record syntax](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html#deftypes.record).

You options are either to use different field names on the record or to put them in separate modules. Because modules do each have their own name space, if you put Square in the Square module and Rectangle in the Rectangle module, you would be able to reuse the field names.

Comment: Placing each type in its own module seems something of an overkill. I realised that accessor functions were created but I was rather hoping that type inference would select the correct field name to use.

Comment: Yes, I agree that in this case separating into modules feels like overkill. I'd probably just change the field names. Something like `rectUpperLeft`isn't a ton longer than `upperLeft`. 


I agree that reusing field names seems like a useful and reasonable thing to expect, but as far as I know, you just can't do that with Haskell's records.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to get away with putting the Square constructor in the Rectangle type since it's really more a specialization of that type.

From typing stuff out in GHCI, this seems to work fine:

```
data Point
    = Point{x::Float,y::Float}
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data Rectangle
    = Rectangle {upperLeft::Point, bottomRight::Point}
    | Square    {upperLeft::Point, bottomRight::Point}
    deriving (Eq, Show)

let r = Rectangle (Point 3.0 4.0) (Point 4.0 2.0)
let s = Square (Point 2.0 4.0) (Point 4.0 2.0)
```

Then you can call both:

```
upperLeft s
upperLeft r
```

Though you might want to change the Square since it has some constraints it must meet:

```
data Rectangle
    = Rectangle {upperLeft::Point, bottomRight::Point}
    | Square    {upperLeft::Point, size::Float}
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```